# Comment appears in the inbox, but not in the responses

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, comment-replies, responses

On 2011-03-27, 20:52:22 I received a comment to [this answer on tex.sx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11166/how-to-change-hsize-in-the-middle-of-a-paragraph-at-pagebreak-especially-for-tw/13022#13022). I got notified in my inbox, and it's still there in the inbox, but when I go to [my "responses" tab on tex.sx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1235/hendrik-vogt?tab=responses) (I guess most users won't get to see my responses if they click the link), then the last comment there is from 2011-03-26, 14:40:09.

Ah, I just see, [the old "responses" tag on my `/recent` page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/recent/1235?Tab=Responses&StartDate=2011-03-27&EndDate=2011-03-28) has quite a few comments of the past 2 days that are *not* in that other "responses" tab.

What's wrong with the new "responses" tab in my profile?

Comment: Since only moderators on the valid site can see your responses tab, would you care to share some of the example comments that were *not* shown on your profile version? I can't see anything suspicious about the particular one on the 27th, so I'm wondering if I can spot any form of trend based on multiple samples.

Comment: Oh, I think I've figured it out, based on my own profile. The "responses" tab in your profile seems to only track responses *on posts that you own*. If you get @pinged on someone else's posts (like for me, if you were to respond to me right here), they won't show up in your profile. I can post this as an answer, unless you're interested in converting this into a feature-request to revise this functionality.

Comment: @Grace: Thanks a lot for figuring this out. Yes, it would be great if you could post this as an answer; I think this could also be helpful to others. I can still make a separate feaure-request.

Comment: @Hendrik - No need for a feature-request, this is a bug - I'm fixing it now.

Comment: I would translate my comment to an answer, but since @Nick is fixing this now, his answer's going to supercede mine and explain it, which leaves my answer to be terribly redundant. So I'll just happily wait for the status-completed ♪

Comment: @Nick: Ah, thanks a lot, I was just about to remove the "bug" tag ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out when I converted all of the responses code (comments, answers, revisions) I missed one case, which is the @reply style comments on posts you don't own (if you owned them, you'd see the comments anyway).

We just pushed out a change that rectifies this, you should now see all the @reply comments appearing in your responses tab, regardless of who owns the post.

Comment: Confirmed, thanks to comments on this very question. Nicely nicely. ♪

Comment: Yep, all the comments are now in the new "responses" tab - thanks, that was quick!