# Comment appears in the inbox, but not in the responses

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-replies, responses

This is somehow a continuation of my bug report [Comment appears in the inbox, but not in the responses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85047) (with the exact same title, but the previous bug was fixed).

Yesterday I got 4 comment @replies from [Gilles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/149076/gilles) in my inbox, all on the post [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019) Some of those comments are edited and didn't include "@Hendrik" when they were first posted, but some contained "@Hendrik" from the very beginning. However, *none* of the comments appears in the "responses" in my profile's "activity" tab. (There are only 2 entries for yesterday in the "responses", both of them comment @replies that came due to others using "@Hendrik".)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those comments should have worked, this stemmed from an error in our responses SQL, the portion that grabs @reply comments wasn't quite right and is now fixed.

You'll now see these comment replies in your responses tab.

---

Since many users like detailed bug porn, here's what was wrong:

```sql
SELECT c.ReplyToUserId, c.UserId, c.CreationDate, c.Id, 2
FROM PostComments c
     INNER JOIN Posts p ON p.Id = c.PostId
WHERE p.OwnerUserId <> c.ReplyToUserId
  AND p.DeletionDate IS NULL
  AND c.DeletionDate IS NULL
```

The problem with this was that in SQL server that `<>` comparison is just thrown out in the case of an answer like you linked, since `p.OwnerUserId` is `NULL` on those posts.  Since we want to show it doesn't match the owner in this case a simple `IsNull(p.OwnerUserId, 0)` will suffice...and that's deployed across all sites now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I do now see the comments in my responses - great! Also thanks for the porn, even if I don't understand it.